# How to properly order async functions in node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, botframework, adaptive-cards

i got 3 adaptive cards that should display correctly one after the other, depending on which button is pushed. Unfortunately they just show randomly till the wished one appears. My function is pretty miserable and consumes too much in testing. Any suggestion is welcomed.

InputCard works fine cos is attached at the beginning in  the index.js file, the mess starts later with the three ones exposed here. InputCard is repeated cos of the context.sendActivity('Back to menu').

```
async processCards (context, luisResult, next) {
    this.logger.log('process');

    // Retrieve LUIS result for Process Automation.
    const result = luisResult.connectedServiceResult;
    const intent = result.topScoringIntent.intent;

    let InputCard = require('../resources/FaqCard.json');
    let InputCard1 = require('../resources/InputCard.json');
    let InputCard3 = require('../resources/UserPsw.json');
    let CARDS = [
        InputCard,
        InputCard1,
        InputCard3
    ];
    let reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };
    let buttons = [

        { type: ActionTypes.Submit, title: 'F.A.Q', value: '1' },
        { type: ActionTypes.Submit, title: 'Back to menu', value: '2' },
        { type: ActionTypes.Submit, title: 'login', value: '3' }

    ];
    let card = CardFactory.heroCard('say what???', undefined,
        buttons, { text: 'You can upload an image or select one of the following choices.' });

    reply.attachments = [card];
    let SelectedCard = CARDS[Math.floor((Math.random() * CARDS.length - 1) + 1)];

    if (await context.sendActivity(`F.A.Q`))
        return context.sendActivity({
            attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(SelectedCard)]
        });

    if (await context.sendActivity('Back to menu'))
        return context.sendActivity({
            attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(SelectedCard) = this.CARDS(InputCard)]
        });
    if (await context.sendActivity('login'))
        return context.sendActivity({
            attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(SelectedCard) = this.CARDS(InputCard3)]
        });
    await context.sendActivity(`processCards top intent ${intent}.`);
    await context.sendActivity(`processCards intents detected:  ${luisResult.intents.map((intentObj) => intentObj.intent).join('\n\n')}.`);


    if (await context.sendActivity(`myName ${intent}.` == 'myName')) {
        return context.sendActivity(`ok, anything else????`);
    }
    if (luisResult.entities.length > 0) {
        await context.sendActivity(`processCards entities were found in the message: ${luisResult.entities.map((entityObj) => entityObj.entity).join('\n\n')}.`);
        await context.sendActivity(`ok, anything else?`);

    }
    await next();
}
```

After InputCard,should be possible to choose between FaqCard.json or UserPsw.json and after that,if wished,  returning to InputCard too.

Comment: There are a number of things I don't understand about your function, but let's start here: why do you randomize your cards and then try and match on them? What is the purpose behind that?

Comment: There is just so much that is wrong with this.